# Store stdout and stderr in file, then recreate the output later

Tags: io-redirection, storage, stdout, file-descriptors

I've redirected output to a file like so:

```
$ ./test.bash 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /' >> output) > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /' >> output)
$ cat output
  stdout: Hello World!
  stderr: error
```

I would like to precisely reproduce the output of the original command `./test.bash`.  This is what I tried:

```
$ cat output | tee >(grep '^stdout: '|sed 's/^stdout: //') >(grep '^stderr: '|sed 's/^stderr: //' 1>&2) >/dev/null 2>&1 | cat
  error
  Hello World!
```

Obviously, I would like the output to be in the right order.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What is "normal"? Why are you adding `stdout` only to remove it later? Is this part of a larger project? If not, why not just do `sed 's/^stdout: *//;s/^stderr: *//' output`?

Comment: @terdon The point is that stderr needs to be outputted to stderr, not to stdout.  If you know of a way to record stdout and stderr separately, elegantly, and in a way that preserves the order, I'd love to hear it.  That's why I'm here.

Comment: @terdon Since it's hard to find the "original command" underneath the meta-script, I edited my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your current file probably this would do:

```
awk '
    /^stdout:/ { print substr($0, 9) } 
    /^stderr:/ { print substr($0, 9) > "/dev/stderr" }
    ' output
```

It could get a bit more elegant with some changes to your "recording script".

Answer (score 2):

if your `test.bash` looks like this:

```
echo "Hello World!"; echo error >&2
```

this script `loop.sh`:

```
./test.bash &> original ; echo original: ; cat original;     ok=0 ; er=0
for i in {1..100}; do
   rm output ; printf "(ok%d:er%d) running again: " $ok $er
   ./test.bash 2> >(cat >>output) > >(cat >>output)  #<-EXAMINED COMMAND
   if diff output original >/dev/null;
      then printf "result equal...."; ((ok++))
      else printf "result DIFFERENT"; ((er++)); fi
done
```

should prove that the output file is often ordered *wrongly* (~37% in my test)

Problem is messing with parallel processes, uncontrolled redirection buffering and execution speeds.

Solution with tool "unbuffer" from "expect" packet (if you can install it). Using:

```
(sleep 0.01 ; unbuffer ./test.bash)
```

instead of just ./test.bash in 4th line of above script, will do perfect (0% errors).

Comment: FloHimself's answer is pretty excellent.  Perhaps I may not be able to replicate it exactly, but I can get pretty close, especially considering that the parallel processes should take about the same amount of time.  And, since I'm just using this for logging (our third party logging script colorizes stderr), it works well enough for me.

Comment: @Jack yes, answer is great for parsing output. It just seems that output file itself will be wrong ordered already... maybe i am missing something.

Comment: If you have a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @Jack - this isn't impossible to do by any means. In fact, your shell provides a few useful guideposts for marking I/O programmatically - namely, `$PS[124]`. Use those with `exec` and `tee`/`tail -f`  and you can manage this all right.

Comment: That's really not a very good way to do that. With `read`, like that? Better is to get a shell shell. Or, in other words, just some dummy interface between the keyboard and your processing. You can do it with `bash` like `bash -nv 2 >&1 | while process; do ... `

Comment: @mikeserv read is not important at all DIFF is doing processing and check, you can put 'for i in {1..100}' instead of while, and remove read

Comment: `for i in {1..` is another bad way to go - and of *course* `diff` is going to be buffering - but you can fix that if you just wrap it in a pty. You might get one with `luit` like `luit -olog /dev/fd/3 diff 3>&1 >/dev/null | some other command` but it would be easier to use `stdbuf`.

Comment: @mikeserv ...wrapping it in a pty - good advice i have a solution.

Comment: See? Not impossible. You can do it with standard tools as well if you're any good with `dd`. And if you script the shell's prompts you can do it without that if you setup a few traps,

Answer (score 0):

If all of your input lines start with either `stderr:` or `stdout:`, you could do:

```
perl -ne 's/^std(...):\s*//; $1 eq "err" ? print STDERR : print' output
```

Or, with recent versions of bash

```
while read -r out line; do
    [[ $out =~ ^stderr ]] && echo "$line" >&2 || echo "$line"
done < output
```

Comment: What is `$out`? And why does the entire `while` loop have its stdout redirected to `/dev/null`?